# action href link in wpf webbrowser control via code

Tags: c#, html, wpf-controls

i use the wpf webbrowser control to show manual generated html code via WebBrowser.NavigateToString() method. In this html code there are many manual links like the following example:

```
<a href="#marker_1">Go to Mark 1</a>
```

When i click on this link in the html document thr browser jump to it. It works correctly. What i want is to jump to the marker via c# code. I know that the WebBrowser.Document Property is a IHtmlDocument from Microsoft.mshtml.dll. I cast it an the enumarte through all IHtmlAncorElements. The i find the Ancor via name and cast it back to IHtmlElement. So i have the IHtmlElement object but i dont no how can i cation the link like also in this  mock-code:

```
var ancorElement = ((IHtmlDocument)WebBrowser.Document).all.Cast<IHtmlElement>().Where(element => elment is IHtmlAncorElement).FirstOrDefault(element => element.href.equals("#marker_1")); 
if (ancorElement != null) /* so i don't know the right way */ ancorElement.Click() or ancorElement.Action()
```

So  i hope any know a way to run the link via c# code!

Best regards

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

```
                    if (ancorElement != null)
                           WpExample.Navigate("your URL");
```

Is this what you mean? i have found it hard to understand your question but to navigate to different URL using WPF you can do it this way?

Comment: Hello Josh, sorry my english is not so good, so i hope you can understand it a little bit. What i want is to jump to any part of my html generated code in c#. When i use a click on a <a href/> link in the code via webbrowser the it jump automaticly to the part. The same procedure i want to do via code. I have a list with id strings var ids = new List<string>{"#id_1","#_id2"}. Then i want the browser say "WebBrowser jump to part with id_1" in equals when i click in a webbrowser on the link <a href="#id_2">To Part 2</a>!